# Combine yielded values into a list

Tags: python

I wish to create a list of objects in a unit test, but skip an object's creation if its corresponding config is None. This is an attempt, but can it be done better?

```
def object_factory(config, model):
    if config is not None:
        yield model(**config)

def objects_factory(config1, config2):
    return list(
        chain(
            object_factory(config1, Model1),
            object_factory(config2, Model2)
        )
    )
```

So this input:

```
objects_factory(None, {pk=1})
```

will give the following:

```
[Model2(pk=1)]
```

and this:

```
objects_factory({pk=1}, {pk=1})
```

will give me:

```
[Model1(pk=1), Model2(pk=1)]
```

Comment: Please give your input and desire output.

Comment: Your `objects_factory` always contains two arguments?

Comment: @Abdul Niyas P M Yes

Comment: What about `[Object(**config) for config in (config1, config2) if config is not None]`?

Comment: @Abdul Niyas P M Updated question to make it clearer

Comment: @R. Baraiya Added input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension like this should suffice for your purpose:

```
models = Model1, Model2
def objects_factory(*configs):
    return [model(**config) for model, config in zip(models, configs) if config]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/GainsboroDualLogins